# Construct a Doc object with labeled offset data

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a labeled dataset in the [spacy offset format](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#updating).

e.g.:
`('I love Berlin!', {'entities': [(7, 13, 'CITY')]})`

My goal is to convert the format to the [CONLL](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2003/ner/) column format.

`e.g.:
I O
love O
Berlin CITY
! O`

Is there a way to construct a spacy Doc object with only using the labeled data in offset format? If I can construct a Doc object, it should be easy to achieve my goal using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818504/spacy-to-conll-format-without-using-spacys-sentence-splitter).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out the [`GoldParse` utility functions](https://spacy.io/api/goldparse#util) that can convert entity offsets to BILUO tags or spaCy `Span` objects. For instance, the `biluo_tags_from_offsets` helper takes a `Doc` object and a list of entity offsets and returns the BILUO tags for the tokens. For example:

```py
from spacy.lang.en import English  # Or whichever language you need
from spacy.gold import biluo_tags_from_offsets

nlp = English()

YOUR_DATA = [
    ('I love Berlin!', {'entities': [(7, 13, 'CITY')]})
]

for text, annotations in YOUR_DATA:
    offsets = annotations["entities"]
    doc = nlp(text)
    tags = biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, offsets)
    print([token.text for token in doc], tags)
```

```
['I', 'love', 'Berlin', '!'] ['O', 'O', 'U-CITY', 'O']
```

This is already very close to the output you're looking for. If the label is not `O`, you can split on the `-` and you have the entity label for the token at that position.